# Endpoints must be full URIs and include a scheme and host , Digitalocean Spaces and Laravel

Tags: laravel, api, digital-ocean

I'm trying to upload files to Digitalocean Spaces using Laravel file system. I followed a tutorial on youtube but I keep getting an error from Laravel saying "Endpoints must be full URIs and include a scheme and host".

This is the tutorial that I followed: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vFwy-vB_d_k&t=776s

Any help would be appreciated.

In the config/filesystems.config I have added this

```
        'do_spaces' => [
        'driver' => 's3',
        'key' => env('DO_SPACES_KEY'),
        'secret' => env('DO_SPACES_SECRET'),
        'region' => env('DO_SPACES_REGION'),
        'bucket' => env('DO_SPACES_BUCKET'),
        'endpoint' => env('DO_SPACES_ENDPOINT'),
    ],
```

In my .env file

```
DO_SPACES_KEY= secret
DO_SPACES_SECRET= secret
DO_SPACES_REGION=nyc3
DO_SPACES_BUCKET= afghanjamtest
DO_SPACES_ENDPOINT= https://nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com
```

This is my code for my controller

```
    $input=$request->all();
    $songs=array();
    if($files=$request->file('files')){
        foreach($files as $file){
            $name=$file->getClientOriginalName();

            $path = Storage::disk('do_spaces')->putFileAs('uploads', $file, $name);

            // $file->move('songs',$name);
            $songs[]=$name;

        }
    }

    return redirect('/show');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change yours env variables:

```
DO_SPACES_KEY='secret'
DO_SPACES_SECRET='secret'
DO_SPACES_REGION='nyc3'
DO_SPACES_BUCKET='afghanjamtest'
DO_SPACES_ENDPOINT='https://nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com'
```

Whitout spaces and between ' or " because sometimes the secret has a char # and it is a special char in env files.

Answer (score -2):

configuration is good but You need to delete caches from config.

1. close server if running (because you also need to restart server to env changes take effect)
2. php artisan clear:data
3. php artisan cache:clear

Now run server again, and hope it will work.